# unit test exception handled by try catch

Tags: c#, unit-testing, exception, try-catch, appsettings

I have catered for the situation when a config key has not been set in my business logic as follows:

```
public class Presenter
{
private readonly IView view;     

    public Presenter(IView view) 
    {
    this.view = view;        
    }

    public void DoStuff() 
    {
        try
        {
            String someKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomeKey"].ToString();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(someKey))
            {                    
                throw new InvalidOperationException("SomeKey not set.");
            }

            // do stuff
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
        {
            // provide view with friendly error

            // log error                
        }
    }
}
```

My attempt at testing that this error occurrs when the key is not set:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Presenter_DoStuff_Should_Throw_InvalidOperationException_When_SomeKey_Not_Supplied()
{
    // Arrange
    mockIView = new Mock<IView>();            
    presenter = new Presenter(mockIView.Object);

    // Act

    // Assert     
    // NUnit here as more precise       
    NUnit.Framework.Assert.Throws<InvalidOperationException>(() => presenter.DoStuff(), "SomeKey not set.");
}
```

1. How do I get my test to pass as it stands? It currently fails because the try-catch is swallowing the exception for logging purposes. The test passes without the try-catch. This is with the `AppSettings["SomeKey"]` manually set to empty string.
2. Secondly, how do I specify in the test that `someKey` in `DoStuff` is empty to actually test this situation without having to manually remove the key setting?

Any help is greatly appreciated as I'm new to unit testing.

Comment: Why are you using exceptions for logic flow?  A simple `if` statement to check whether or not the config setting is present would work just as well.  Exceptions should be used for exceptional behavior, not simple conditional checks.  As for the test, your method doesn't actually *throw* an exception to calling code, so the test it incorrect.  What are you actually trying to *validate* in the test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your test is invalid by design because your method doesn't actually *throw* an exception to calling code.  This is because you immediately catch and handle that exception.  This is actually a very incorrect use of exceptions.  There's no need to throw based on a condition and then immediately catch when all you logically need to do is check that condition.  Something like this:

```
public void DoStuff()
{
    var someKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomeKey"];
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(someKey))
    {
        // provide view with friendly error
        // log error
        return;
    }
    // do stuff
}
```

Now the question becomes... what are you testing?  The actual business logic of this method is in:

```
// do stuff
```

So hopefully that's the critical focus of the testing.  Now, in order to reach 100% code coverage, you do also need to test what's in that conditional block.  In order to do that, you need to simulate the condition.  However, you have an external dependency:

```
ConfigurationManager
```

In order to test the logic, you're going to need to mock that dependency.  A general approach to this is to create a kind of wrapper object for the dependency.  In this specific case it could be something as simple as:

```
public class ConfigurationWrapper
{
    public virtual string SomeKey
    {
        get
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomeKey"];
        }
    }
}
```

This could be separate from the class that has `DoStuff`, or even nested within.  Depends on where/how else you'd want to use it.  And of course it can be extended to wrap other configuration dependencies.  Then within the class which has `DoStuff` you'd create a property for this wrapper.  Something like this:

```
private ConfigurationWrapper _config;
public ConfigurationWrapper Configuration
{
    get
    {
        if (_config == null)
            _config = new ConfigurationWrapper();
        return _config;
    }
    set { _config = value; }
}
```

And use it in `DoStuff()`:

```
var someKey = this.Configuration.SomeKey;
```

Now the dependency on `ConfigurationManager` is wrapped in a mockable object.  So in your unit test you'd create a mock `ConfigurationWrapper` object and set it on the object being tested.  Something like:

```
var mockConfig = new Mock<ConfigurationWrapper>();
presenter.Configuration = mockConfig;
```

You can set your mock to return either a valid value or an empty string for the `.SomeKey` property, depending on what any given test needs.  And then you'd validate whatever side-effect is produced by the conditional statement.  (The "friendly error message" and the "logging" I assume.  Which may involve further mocks, I can't know at this time.)

Of course, to reach 100% coverage you'd also need to add another test for the default case of the wrapper when one isn't externally set.  That should be a fairly simple test:

```
// arrange
// no mocks to set up

// act
var presenter = new Presenter(null);

// assert
Assert.IsNotNull(presenter.Configuration);
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing a few things up for me. Much appreciated.